# How to stretch a list view to the full screen in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Supose I have a layout oriented vertically with one button in the top, a list view in the middle, and a button in the bottom:

```
------
BUTTON
LISTVIEW
LISTVIEW
LISTVIEW
------
```

I would like to make the whole layout scrollable, to be able to see the full list when scrolling down it:

```
------
LISTVIEW
LISTVIEW
LISTVIEW
BUTTON
------
```

Comment: Surrond all these with `<ScrollView> ... <ScrollView />` in the `xml`.

Comment: @g00dy it is a bad practice to put `Listview` inside `ScrollView`

Comment: @MocialovBoris - yes, it's scrollable (the listview), but the buttons are not and if they are all enveloped with a layout, this whole thing can be made scrollable.

Comment: @g00dy isn't it better and easier to just use header and footer of `ListView` component?

Comment: @Didac Can you clear what you want to achieve :  1. What happens in onClick() of the top & bottom btn.  2 . Is the entire list always available on scroll with its area of coverage of screen being changed dynamically?

Comment: @MocialovBoris - yes it is way better like that. Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it, here's a solution for you, without using `ScrollView` (which is actually not needed):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

<Button android:id="@+id/btn1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list1"
          android:layout_height="0dip"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list2"
          android:layout_height="0dip"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list3"
          android:layout_height="0dip"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button android:id="@+id/btn2" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to the header of a ListView and a button to the bottom of the ListView

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Button as header and a Button as footer to the ListView.
2. Write a custom Adapter for the ListView, return Button view at 0 and last position in getView().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if you want to be able to scroll the buttons too, depending on that there are two ways which you can try. First where the button won't change their position while list view is scrolling. In this situation your xml should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/top_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second option is when you want these two buttons to scroll while list view is scrolling too. To achieve this you should add `Button`s to your list view as header and footer :

```
mListView.addHeader(myFirstButton);
mListView.addFooter(mySecondButton);
```

And that should do the trick for you in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`